# Should I add a 'mechanisms' tag?

Tags: discussion

I've been doing some tag edits as time permits.

Realizing one of our problems is the sheer number of tags, I hate to say it, but I've been thinking of adding a 'mechanisms' tag. We have lots of questions about various mechanical devices  on and around spacecraft, but I didn't see an applicable tag.

For instance, this question [ISS Structural Integrity](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23733/6944) could really use another tag besides 'iss', and 'mechanisms' seems to fit the bill.

Edit 2: Looks like 'avionics' exists, yay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd be ok with such a tag if it was rigorously defined in the tag excerpt, but keep in mind we have other related tags we would need to distinguish it from as well (see comments below). We actually *did* have such a tag just last week. I removed it because it had only two unrelated uses, where there were better tags available.

Comment: Something to keep in mind: in cases where [tag:electronics], [tag:avionics], [tag:robotics], [tag:sensors], [tag:instrument] or [tag:equipment] would work, we probably don't need "mechanisms".

Comment: Also, these have more specialized uses but should also be preferred when applicable: [tag:turbomachinery], [tag:gyroscope], [tag:reaction-wheel], [tag:telecommunication], [tag:antenna], [tag:gps], [tag:reduced-gravity-manufacturing], [tag:computer], [tag:radio-communication], [tag:laser], [tag:solar-panel], [tag:service-utilities], and [tag:microscope]. Not all of these may be considered "mechanisms" anyway, but they are certainly types of devices that we have tags for that should be used when more pertinent.

Comment: I don't see much overlap in the cases in your first comment, so that shouldn't be a problem.  Or in the second comment.

Comment: I wrote it up as follows: Mechanisms are mechanical systems used on spacecraft and/or ground support equipment for spacecraft. The mechanisms may be manually (for example, ISS personnel airlock hatches), electrically (for example, ISS Common Berthing Mechanism latches), hydraulically (for example, shuttle Orbiter landing gear uplock hooks), or pneumatically actuated (for example, shuttle Orbiter 17" feedline disconnect valve latches).

Comment: @OrganicMarble Looks great! Thanks for writing that up!

Comment: @OrganicMarble All that remains to do now is to help apply the tag going forward and make sure it doesn't get used incorrectly.